# PCA for Matlab not working?

Tags: matlab, pca

Somthing super weird going on in here,

I try to replicate the website Matlab example for PCA:

```
load hald

     coeff = pca(ingredients)
     coeff =

       -0.0678   -0.6460    0.5673    0.5062
       -0.6785   -0.0200   -0.5440    0.4933
        0.0290    0.7553    0.4036    0.5156
        0.7309   -0.1085   -0.4684    0.4844
```

But when I apply the same exact thing I get:

```
coeff = pca(ingredients)

coeff =

   36.8218    6.8709
   29.6073   -4.6109
  -12.9818    4.2049
   23.7147    6.6341
   -0.5532    4.4617
  -10.8125    3.6466
  -32.5882   -8.9798
   22.6064  -10.7259
   -9.2626   -8.9854
   -3.2840   14.1573
    9.2200  -12.3861
  -25.5849    2.7817
  -26.9032    2.9310
```

Any clues for this? Driving me crazy!
Thanks 
Cheers
Emiliano

Comment: I reproduced the MATLAB example's output but not your output. Can you clear the workspace and try again?

Comment: I have close matlab, and re-opend and now it worked out, any clue why was that? Thanks man

Comment: You must have modified `ingredients` without realizing/remembering that you did so.

Comment: mmm it most be somthing inherent to matlab, because when I clear de workspace the error persist just when I open and close matlab it gives me the expected output

Comment: I realized that when I add the folder i am working to the path the pca function changes and does not reply as normal anymore, crazy, let me know me if you have any clue on why is that cheers

Comment: Do you have functions or files named `pca` by any chance? That may shadow MATLAB's built-in `pca` function.

Comment: you are my hero man! I actually found a pca function in the folder, so not clever... thanks!